# Postgres 11: Not using the correct indices after upgrade

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-9.6

We upgraded lately our database from PostgreSQL 9.6 to 11 on RDS (after the upgrade we did `vacuum full` and `analyze` for the DB).

We noticed that a frequent query changed its execution plan, and now it is not using the correct indices.

```
SELECT "posts".*
FROM "posts"
WHERE "posts"."delete_at" IS NULL
  AND "posts"."tenant_id" = 1582
  AND "posts"."approved" = TRUE
  AND (posts.status in (0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9))
ORDER BY id desc
LIMIT 3000 OFFSET 0
```

The query is doing lots of filters and has `limit`+`offset` for pagination.
The most helpful filters here are `tenant_id` and `status`, on which we have a compound index for it.

In Postgres 9.6 the execution plan is:

```
Limit  (cost=36057.09..36064.59 rows=3000 width=1082) (actual time=7.159..8.404 rows=2018 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=36057.09..36130.91 rows=29529 width=1082) (actual time=7.159..7.664 rows=2018 loops=1)
        Sort Key: id DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1091kB
        ->  Index Scan using index_posts_on_tenant_id_and_status on posts  (cost=0.56..34204.03 rows=29529 width=1082) (actual time=0.022..5.052 rows=2018 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((tenant_id = 1582) AND (status = ANY ('{0,1,2,3,6,9}'::integer[])))
              Filter: ((delete_at IS NULL) AND approved)
Planning time: 0.289 ms
Execution time: 8.856 ms
```

The execution time is fast and we are using our compound index.

In Postgres 11:

```
Limit  (cost=1000.49..30635.60 rows=3000 width=1149) (actual time=7.064..2100.604 rows=2479 loops=1)
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.49..1138801.15 rows=115181 width=1149) (actual time=7.062..2101.843 rows=2479 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 4
        Workers Launched: 4
        ->  Parallel Index Scan Backward using posts_pkey on posts  (cost=0.43..1124081.93 rows=28795 width=1149) (actual time=1.831..1679.456 rows=496 loops=5)
              Filter: ((delete_at IS NULL) AND approved AND (tenant_id = 1582) AND (status = ANY ('{0,1,2,3,6,9}'::integer[])))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 1187090
Planning Time: 1.134 ms
Execution Time: 2102.218 ms
```

We are not using the compound index and get poor performance.

We did some experiments and found interesting things.

First experiment - the tenant has 2400-2500 posts; if we change the limit to be 2400 and not 3000 (the default one):

```
Limit  (cost=1000.49..24708.58 rows=2400 width=1149) (actual time=7.716..39.017 rows=2400 loops=1)
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.49..1138801.15 rows=115181 width=1149) (actual time=7.715..38.848 rows=2400 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 4
        Workers Launched: 4
        ->  Parallel Index Scan Backward using posts_pkey on posts  (cost=0.43..1124081.93 rows=28795 width=1149) (actual time=2.092..23.554 rows=494 loops=5)
              Filter: ((delete_at IS NULL) AND approved AND (tenant_id = 1582) AND (status = ANY ('{0,1,2,3,6,9}'::integer[])))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 12398
Planning Time: 0.271 ms
Execution Time: 39.158 ms
```

We get a fast execution time and still using the wrong index.

The second experiement - and this is the interesting one - we change the order by to be `created_at` and not `id` (it is important to note: we have an index on `id DESC` for this kind of query):

```
Limit  (cost=193711.00..193991.02 rows=2400 width=1149) (actual time=5.473..7.277 rows=2400 loops=1)
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=193711.00..204909.92 rows=95984 width=1149) (actual time=5.472..7.093 rows=2400 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Sort  (cost=192710.98..192830.96 rows=47992 width=1149) (actual time=2.901..2.948 rows=816 loops=3)
              Sort Key: created_at DESC
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 778kB
              Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 273kB
              Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 327kB
              ->  Parallel Index Scan using index_posts_on_tenant_id_and_status on posts  (cost=0.56..189776.55 rows=47992 width=1149) (actual time=0.052..2.045 rows=826 loops=3)
                    Index Cond: ((tenant_id = 1582) AND (status = ANY ('{0,1,2,3,6,9}'::integer[])))
                    Filter: ((delete_at IS NULL) AND approved)
Planning Time: 0.279 ms
Execution Time: 7.473 ms
```

We get a fast execution time and are using the correct compound index.

We don't know why this happens, and don't want to change our code for the new order by since we want to understand what's going on here.

We tried:

- running `analyze` on the posts table - didn't help.
- upgrading to strong machine 2x memory and 2x CPU - didn't help.
- we removed 50% of rows which are marked as `delete_at` and then run again `analyze` - didn't help.
- Used `CREATE STATISTICS` with `dependencies` on `tenant_id` and `status` and ran `analyze` - and got the exact same execution plan.
- Disabled parallelism on Postgres 11 - got 2x slower execution time.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is of this shape:

```
SELECT ...
FROM atable
WHERE <condition>
ORDER BY <expression>
LIMIT n;
```

There are two approaches to process a query like that

1. Use indexes to speed up `<condition>` and sort the result.
2. Use an index on `<expression>` to get the results in sorted order and discard everything that does not satisfy `<condition>` until we reach the `LIMIT`.

Now it seems that the cost estimates for both paths are pretty close: 36000 vs. 30500, and the estimate in the latter case is so low only because you have 5 cores working on the query. You must have increased `max_parallel_workers_per_gather`, and from the "short" execution time of 2 seconds I even suspect that you artificially increased the degree of parallelism by setting the `parallel_workers` storage parameter on the table.

Moreover, PostgreSQL 9.6 doesn't have parallel index scan, so it isn't even tempted to choose the second path, because with one process the index scan would take longer.

Now that strategy does not work out: In reality, there are only 2479 matching rows rather than the estimated 28795, so the index scan cannot stop early, but has to scan the complete index, because the `LIMIT` is never reached. Index scans are slow, so the plan performs much worse than PostgreSQL thought.

In a way, the increased capabilities in v11 opened the door to yet another way to process the query that turned out to be a trap.

What can you do to put PostgreSQL on the right track:

- The crude method: change the `ORDER BY` clause so that it doesn't match the indexed expression:

  ```
  ORDER BY id + 0
  ```

  Then the bad road is blocked. But it can also not be taken in cases where it would be the better road...
- The better method: reduce the degree of parallelism, either by lowering `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` globally or by setting the `parallel_workers` storage parameter on the table to a lower value.

  Then perhaps that plan will become less attractive. It may not work out, because the other plan could also be parallelized.
- Maybe the best method: Try to fix the row count mis-estimate so that PostgreSQL knows what to expect.

  ```
  ALTER INDEX posts
     ALTER status SET STATISTICS 1000,
     ALTER tenant_id SET STATISTICS 1000;
  ANALYZE posts;
  ```

  Then see if the estimate is better.

  If that does not do the trick, try extended statistics:

  ```
  CREATE STATISTICS posts_ext_stats (dependencies)
     ON tenant_id, status FROM posts;
  ANALYZE posts;
  ```

Comment: My comment was not formatted well, so I will write it in multiple comments. sorry.

Comment: Disabling parallelism / CREATE STATISTICS - didn't help us and updated the main post.

Comment: No, `SET STATISTICS` does not fix the statistics, it tells PostgreSQL to collect more detailed statistics.

Comment: ALERT .. SET STATISTICS - I am afraid of this, since this is static value and thinks can change for better or worse.

Comment: ORDER BY id + 0 - fixes the issue and it's the same as order by created_at - we will evaluate this.

Comment: Oh, So SET STATISTICS will make it collect more detailed statistics and it will still be dynamic?

Comment: I recommend that you play with my three ideas, perhaps with different settings of parallelism and statistics granularity; perhaps you can find the sweet spot that way.

Comment: Yes, as I said, it just makes PostgreSQL collect ten time as many data points whenever `ANALYZE` is run.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104109/discussion-between-yosi-and-laurenz-albe).

Answer (score 0):

1. use noop function `coalesce(column)` - easiest
2. add `desc nulls last` or `asc nulls first` - depends on order
3. use expression `column+0` - depends on type

---

What you want is prevent choosing ordered index.

When order+limit postgres prefer ordered index by [this](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_13_STABLE/src/backend/optimizer/util/pathnode.c#L3748), because order+limit may exit early.

```c
            *total_cost = *startup_cost +
                (input_total_cost - input_startup_cost)
                * count_rows / input_rows;
```

- count_rows = limit
- input_rows = rows or n_distinct or calc by histogram - depends on filter

```
count_rows / input_rows
```

e.g. limit 30, rows 30k -> 0.001 - this will makes the cost lower than other candidate plans.

you can check n_distinct by

```sql
SELECT attname,
       n_distinct,
       null_frac
FROM pg_stats
WHERE tablename = 'table1'
  and attname in ('column1', 'column2');
```

STATISTICS may change the n_distinct, but if the data is low cardinality, STATISTICS is useless here.